# QML Transition Animation using Animators and PropertyAnimation Combined

Tags: qt, animation, qml, qt5

Facing some issue using QML Animatiors in state Transition animations. Here is my working sample Code. In this sample if I decide not to provide "from" Attribute for the OpacityAnimator( reason is i wanted it to consider the current property value) the animator is not animating the property.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    property bool isOpen: false
    Button {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "Fade Animation Open Layer "
        onClicked: {
            isOpen = true;
            overlay.state = "open";
        }
    }
    Rectangle {
        id: overlay
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "green"
        visible: isOpen
        opacity: 0
        Button {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: "Close Overlay"
            onClicked: {
                overlay.state = "close"
            }
        }

        state: "close"
        states: [
            State {
                name: "hidden"
            },
            State {
                name: "visible"
            }
        ]
        transitions: [
            Transition {
                from: "close"
                to: "open"
                OpacityAnimator {
                    target: overlay
                    from: 0.0
                    to: 1.0
                    duration: 600
                    easing.type: Easing.OutCubic
                }


            },
            Transition {
                from: "open"
                to: "close"
                SequentialAnimation {
                    OpacityAnimator {
                        target: overlay
                        //from: overlay.opacity
                        to: 0.0
                        duration: 600
                        easing.type: Easing.OutCubic
                    }
                    ScriptAction {
                        script: {
                            isOpen = false;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

If i use PropertyAnimation instead, the fade effect works absolutely fine. So I just digged in to the Animator Code to and found out the below snippet from the apply function of qquickanimator.cpp and assume it means if "from" not specified it is supposed to fetch it from the target's property value and a comment Claims the magic line works like PropertyAnimation. But it is not working this way

```
    if (isFromDefined)
        job->setFrom(from);
    else if (action.fromValue.isValid())
        job->setFrom(action.fromValue.toReal());
    else
        job->setFrom(action.property.read().toReal());

// This magic line is in sync with what PropertyAnimation does
// and prevents the animation to end up in the "completeList"
// which forces action.toValue to be written directly to
// the item when a transition is cancelled.
 action.fromValue = action.toValue;
```

So my Questions are:

1. Is it a Bug in the Qt Animator or am I missing something here?
2. Is it ok to combine PropertyAnimation and Animators(Opacity,Scale) in a Grouped animation(Sequential or Parallel) for a state Transition provided Animators scope is Scene graph and for PropertyAnimation  it's the target object

Comment: Just a comment to tell that I really don't like state and transitions in QML. Behavior are more than enough most of the time and much less verbose. I even wrote some custom ones for common tasks. Here it is applied to your code : https://gist.github.com/oKcerG/c2da0dfb077b661a4afdb03930fb941e

Comment: 1. It's not a bug. Animators are meant for running animation in the rendering thread instead of UI thread. So from the UI thread point of view opacity value jumps from 0 to 1 and vice versa. From documentation: "The value of the QML property will be updated after the animation has finished. The property is not updated while the animation is running."

Answer (score 1):

See this comment in the documentation for the `from` property of Animator:

> If the Animator is defined within a Transition or Behavior, this value defaults to the value defined in the starting state of the Transition, or the current value of the property at the moment the Behavior is triggered.

I think this means it will use the `to` value of `1.0` from the `open` state instead of the current value on the target. Seems like the state machinery is tracking and using how the transitions left things instead of current values.

Your `from: overlay.opacity` should workaround that behavior?

Comment: I suspect the same may be the states transition action is caching the target property after transition and reapplying to the "from". Yes using from: overlay.opacity is indeed working. The PropertyAnimation works well although without "from" in the Transition Animation and ist only the Animators that is behaving this way. Using Animators is mostly preferred because of it's non-Blocking UI thread nature. Since we have many Animators grouped, using from is causing not so smooth Transition.

Comment: Could you explain further your last comment? The from is causing grouped animators to not run smoothly? Could you explain what "not so smooth" means in more detail?